# Hi, Im unable to install package as.Date as R says that as.Date is not available in version 3.6.2

Tags: r

> package ‘as.Date’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)

Hi, I'm unable to install package `as.Date` as R says that `as.Date` is not available in version 3.6.2.

Comment: `as.Date` is a function from `base` package which you don't need to install

Answer (score 1):

That error message appears when you try to insert a package that is not available for said R version. In your case, `as.Date` is not the name of an available package. As per arg0naut's comment, it is actually the name of a R command, [which is available in the `base` package.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/as.Date) The base package is opened automatically when starting R, so you can use the `as.Date` command without manually loading a package.